# Trace of two Dirac matrices in 4 dimensions

Tags: dirac-matrices, trace

I want to show that tr($\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$) = 4$\eta^{\mu \nu}$.
I know that  {$\gamma^\mu , \gamma^\nu$} = 2$\eta^{\mu\nu}I_4$ and tr($\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$) = tr($\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu$),

so tr($\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$) = tr(2$\eta^{\mu\nu} I_4$ - $\gamma^\nu \gamma^\mu$) $\implies$ 2tr($\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu$) = 2tr($\eta^{\mu\nu} I_4$), and ony way to get the answer is by pulling out $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ out of the trace.

I want to ask how we can do that? since $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is itself a matrix, then why it is taken out of the trace and its diagonal elements are not summed?

Comment: This is understandable confusion coming from the fact that $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is *not* a matrix, it is the *components* of a matrix. On the other hand $\gamma^\mu$ *is* a matrix ($\eta^{01}$ is a number, $\gamma^0$ is a matrix). In the definition of the Clifford algebra $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=\eta^{\mu\nu}1$ the $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is multiplied by the identity matrix with spinor components. So when you see $\mathrm{tr}(\eta^{\mu\nu})$ what this actually means is $\eta^{\mu\nu}{1^\alpha}_\alpha$ where $\alpha$ are the spinor components of the identity.

Comment: As a slight amendment to what I've written above, $\mathrm{tr}(\eta^{\mu\nu})$ *can* mean the trace of the matrix whose components are $\eta^{\mu\nu}$, but not in this context. Unfortunately this is common notation.

Comment: Your comment is really helpfull. I need to get some knowledge of Clifford algebra too.

Comment: It does not help that in physics we generally: (1) Straight up don't write spinor indices on things, (2) Call $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ "the metric" when it is really the ($\mu$,$\nu$)'th *component* of the metric when written as a matrix and (3) Don't specify the domain over which the trace function is being defined (from which the question arises, are we taking the trace over the *spinor* indices or over the *4-vector* indices?).

Comment: Thankyou, now it is completely clear. @Charlie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace is over the matrix indices which represent the internal degrees of freedom of the spinor, not over the space-time indices.

Each $\gamma^\mu$ is a matrix, so  if we want to write out all the indices explicitely, it would be $(\gamma^\mu)^{i}_{~~j}$. Then $\{\gamma^\nu,\gamma^\mu\} = 2\eta^{\mu\nu}$ becomes :
$$(\gamma^\mu)^i_{~~j}(\gamma^{\nu})^j_{~~k} + (\gamma^\nu)^i_{~~j}(\gamma^{\mu})^j_{~~k} = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu}\delta^i_k$$

and what you want to show is :
$$(\gamma^\mu)^i_{~~j}(\gamma^\nu)^j_{~~i} = 2 \eta^{\mu\nu}$$

So the short answer is : the $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ goes out of the trace freely.